Device and Network Abuse policy: Unsafe Implementation of TrustManager
I have published my android app on play console and it is giving me this warning.
"We found that your app contains security vulnerabilities, which can expose user information or damage a user’s device. This is a violation of Device and Network Abuse policy. Specifically, your app(s) contain an unsafe implementation of TrustManager."
I am using https in my app still I am getting this warning. Please help.
I am getting a warning from play console regarding trustmanager.

You will need to identify where in your code, or in your included libraries, you are using TrustManager. If it is from a library, see if there is a newer version of the library that fixes its use of TrustManager, or eliminate the library.
